# How can I find cyclic subgroups of $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

We have the group $(S_3, \circ)$, where $S_3=\{(1)(2)(3),(1)(2,3),(1,2)(3),(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(1,3)(2)\}$. How can I find all cyclic subgroups from this?

I know that I *could* go through each element and exponentiate it to see if I get all other terms. However, I would guess there is a more efficient way of solving this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There are only $6$ elements, so it's not much work to go through them.  Do you know how to tell the order of an element of $S_3$?  Do you know that the order of an element must divide the order of the group (which is $6$ in this case, not leaving many possibilities for the order of an element)?

Comment: I do not, and thank you for the welcome!

Comment: The order of a cycle is equal to its length

Comment: So I just completed all of the calculations. I got 5 cyclic subgroups (including the trivial cyclic subgroup). 3 of these are of order 2. One is of order 3. So, I see what you are saying in that the order of one of the cyclic subgroups must divide 6. However, are there any further patterns I can draw from this?

Comment: Good job.  You are correct that $S_3$ has five cyclic subgroups:  one of order $1$, three of order $2$, and one of order $3$.  (The only other subgroup is the entire group, which is not cyclic.)

Comment: Would there be an efficient way to show that the entire group is not cyclic, rather than searching for a generator?

Comment: For one thing, $S_3$ is not Abelian, and cyclic groups are Abelian

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531202/how-many-distinct-subgroups-does-the-symmetric-group-s-3-have), which asks about all subgroups of $S_3,$ not just cyclic ones

Comment: Note:  $S_3$ is not Abelian because $(1,2)(1,3)\ne(1,3)(1,2)$

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help, J.W. Tanner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of an element must divide the order of the group.  The order of $S_3$ is $6$, and $S_3$ is not cyclic; that leaves $1, 2, $ and $3$ as possible orders for elements of $S_3$.  The cyclic group of order $1$ has just the identity element, which you designated $(1)(2)(3)$.  [The order of an element in a symmetric group is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in its cycle decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419937/prove-that-the-order-of-an-element-in-s-n-equals-the-least-common-multiple-of).  Therefore, the orders of $(1)(2,3), (1,2)(3), $ and $(1,3)(2)$ are $2$, and the orders of $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ are $3$.  [The elements of order $2$ are self-inverses.  $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ are inverses of each other.]  $S_3$ is a good example group to study, because it is the smallest non-Abelian group.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric group?

Comment: by symmetric group, basically I mean $S_n$

Comment: Are all $S_n$ groups symmetric? I must have missed learning this property.

Comment: The group $S_n$ is called the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on $n$ letters; elements are bijections of $\{1,2,...,n\}$

Comment: Great- thank you!