# Asymptotics of the number distinct of subgroups of $S_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, asymptotics

I would like to have a sense of the number of distinct subgroups (that is, isomorphic subgroups are counted multiple times) the symmetric group $S_n$ has as $n$ goes to infinity. I suspect nailing down the exact number is harder than understanding the general size. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Pyber has solved this, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76176/enumerating-all-subgroups-of-the-symmetric-group) and its answers.

Comment: There's a general heuristicts that if you want to do some asymptotic enumeration in "uniform among primes" class of finite groups, then 2-primary part quickly become dominating and you can restrict to it. It's almost always true, and this case is not an exception.